# A formula for the smallest $k$ such that $n^{k} > n!$

Tags: number-theory

How to define the smallest exponent k for that $n^{k} > n!$ ?

Does someone know whether exists a formula for that?

For example:

for $n = 2, k = 2,$ since $2^{2} > 2!$

for $n = 3, k = 2,$ since $3^{2} > 3!$

for $n = 4, k = 3,$ since $4^{3} > 4!$

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, $\lceil\log_n(n!)\rceil$ would work.

Comment: you might also want to work out a few more terms, and then search the OEIS https://oeis.org/

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A060151

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may solve
$$
n^x>n!
$$ giving
$$
\begin{align}
x \ln n> \ln (n!)
\end{align}
$$ and, for $n=2,3,\ldots$,
$$
x>\frac{\ln (n!)}{\ln n}.
$$ Then
$$
k:=k_n=\left\lceil\frac{\ln (n!)}{\ln n}\right\rceil.
$$ As $n \to \infty$, this may be approximated by using [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).

Answer (score 2):

If $n$ is large,
$n^k > n!$
is about the same as
$k \ln n
> \ln(n!)
\approx c +\frac12 \ln(n)+n\ln n - n
$
or
$k
\approx \frac12+n- \frac{n-c}{\ln n} 
$
or,
if $\ln n$ is fairly large,
$k \approx \frac12 +n - n/\ln(n)
$.